# Udev Symbolic Link is not trigger on replug

Tags: usb, udev

I am having a very weird behavior with one of my usb device
If the device is plugged in during boot then the symbolic link is correctly followed the udev rule.
However, If I unplug and replug the device, the symbolic link is now pointed to a bus address rather than /dev/tty*. I would have to do sudo udevadm trigger for it to update to correct value.

This is my udev rule

> SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7523", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", MODE:="0666", OWNER:="root", GROUP:="plugdev", SYMLINK+="canusb"

Correct Symbolic Link

> ls /dev/canusb -l
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Jul  5 09:18 /dev/canusb -> ttyUSB0

Wrong Symbolic Link when replug device

> ls /dev/canusb -l
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul  5 09:16 /dev/canusb -> bus/usb/001/005